# How to create a generic <T> class so that T extends Collections<String>?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I want to create a generic `ThreadWorker` class that it's generic type `<T>` accepts classes that extends Collection class of type `<String>`.

I tried:

```
public class Worker <T extends Collections<String>> extends SwingWorker<VectorDetails , String>
```

But I get an error:

```
The type Collections is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>
```

Also when I write:

```
public class Worker <T extends Collections> extends SwingWorker<VectorDetails , String>
```

It compiles fine, but thats not what I need since instances of this Worker class can be created with types of other classes which are not `String`. (Like `< Integer>` , `<Character>` , etc..).

How can I force the user to create instances of my class with types that extends/implements Collection class that holds Strings?

Comment: Did you mean `Collection` (singular)?

Comment: [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is a non-generic class with a bunch of static methods, while [`Collection<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is a generic interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
class StringCollection<T extends Collection<H>, H extends String> {}
```

Comment: Considering `String` is final, the `H extends String` is unnecessary. The question was just a typo.

Comment: yep, ```String``` itself doesn't make much sense in this case, but if you wish to use your own type instead, code above is supposed to work fine :D

Answer (score 1):

The error says what is wrong in the code. `Collections` is not a generic type. It is a utility class with a lot of static methods to manipulate Collection(s). You should use `Collection<String>` or any type. `Collection` is a generic type (which lists and sets extend).